# How do I rotate images woth ImageGrab?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,300,960))
img.rotate(angle=330) #This line does not work
img.show()
```

Image is shown normally. How do I rotate it?

Comment: `img = img.rotate(330)`

Comment: Oh god, of course. Thanks!